# Align pop up window to center of the screen after adding maximizable = true

Tags: css, extjs

After adding attribute "maximizable:true" , a button will be appear on the pop up window . After I click on maximize button, window is moving towards left . It is not coming in the center of the screen .

```
detailsWindow = new Ext.Window( {
                title : 
"Details",
                maximizable:true,
                width:screen.width*.30,
                height:screen.height*.40,
                minWidth:screen.width*.30,
                minHeight:screen.height*.40,
                maxWidth:screen.width*.90,
                maxHeight:screen.height*.85,
                modal: true,
                constrain: true,
                layout: 'fit',
                alwaysOnTop :true,
                autoDestroy:true,
                scrollable:true,
                items : [detailsGrid],
                listeners:{
                    afterrender:function(){
                        Ext.defer(function(){
                            if(this!=null && this.body!=null && this.body.dom!=null){
                                window.scrollTo(this.x,this.y);
                                this.body.dom.scrollTop=0;
                            }
                        },100,this);
                    }
                }   
        });
```

See [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HxOq8.png)

Answer (score 0):

Normally, when you maximize a window it maximizes to the entire screen. But, in your case you have provided min/max height and width. So thats why its not taking full screen size. If you want to position the window at center even after maximizing it then you can add a `maximize listener` and provide a `style` of left as done in below code:

```
Ext.create(Ext.window.Window, {
    title: "Details",
    maximizable: true,
    width: screen.width * .30,
    height: screen.height * .40,
    minWidth: screen.width * .30,
    minHeight: screen.height * .40,
    maxWidth: screen.width * .90,
    maxHeight: screen.height * .85,
    modal: true,
    constrain: true,
    layout: 'fit',
    alwaysOnTop: true,
    autoDestroy: true,
    scrollable: true,
    //                 items : [detailsGrid],
    listeners: {
        afterrender: function () {
            Ext.defer(function () {
                if (this != null && this.body != null && this.body.dom != null) {
                    window.scrollTo(this.x, this.y);
                    this.body.dom.scrollTop = 0;
                }
            }, 100, this);
        },
        maximize: function (win) {
            var width = (screen.width - win.getWidth()) / 2;
            win.setStyle('left', width + 'px');
        }
    }
}).show();
```